# how to NOT write() in binary format

Tags: c, linux

I have a structure, that i want to write to a regular file as one record, with comma delimited fields. For example

```
    struct A {
      int a;
      int b;
   } test;
```

Given `test.a=1` and `test.b = 2`, the regular file will have a corresponding `1,2` as one line record. Another requirement, is that i want to write the entire structure with one system call. So, i created a `char buffer[10]`, stored the value of int a,b into buffer, with comma delimited and a new line character and used Linux system write() call to write the buffer.

The problem is that the record ends up as binary in the file. Which is intuitive as i took away the "typeness" from the variables, the momment i stored them in a char array. I can use standard io, but i would like to learn, how i can achieve the desired results with standard linux system calls with the outlined constraints. How can i preserve the "typness" of a variable. By typeness i mean that if the variable is of type int, the regular file should have human readable digits.

Comment: Do you mean `fprintf(file, "%d, %d\n", a, b);`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  You're saying that you create a human-readable string (presumably with `sprintf` or similar), but then when you write() it, the file contains only binary representation of your values?

Comment: The typeness is applied by the human when reading the untyped human-readbale format. To have both (readabilty for humans and typeness for machines) you need to use human-readable format which incorporates the typeness as well. XML with a suitable scheme might help here. Further reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/

Comment: Why the downvote? This question targets an essential problem, which was around for a long time ... - and hadn't been solved properly before mark-up came in use.

Comment: If you want human-readable with types you must explicitly include the types in the formatted output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking to do is something like `fprintf(fh, "%d,%d\n", test.a, test.b);`, if you open the output file with `fopen`. If you really must use `write()` for some reason, you can `sprintf(buffer, "%d,%d\n", test.a, test.b); write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));`.

Comment: How do fprintf or sprintf achieve the correct result? At the lowest level, i am sure they are using write() also. Do they convert int to its ASCII or similar to make it human readable?

Comment: `sprintf` does not because it only writes to a buffer in memory, not to an output file descriptor. `fprintf` does end up using write() in some way. What matters here is that both are able to translate numbers in binary form to an array of human readable characters.

Comment: It's not what the OP wants, as this way the typness is lost.

Comment: He wants ints to appear as human readable numbers in the output file and he sure as hell got it. How is the typeness lost when all you have are comma separated numbers?

Comment: @whooot: The numbers could have been `long int`s or even `float`s. You **do not** know from the text file.

Comment: @alk I think you are reading more than there is in the question.

Comment: @Jimm: Perhaps you might like to clarify this explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf(fh, "struct:A{int:%d,int:%d}\n", test.a, test.b);`

In some environments you might be able to write:

`fprintf(fh, "struct:%s{%s:%d,%s:%d}\n", typeid(A).name(), typeid(test.a).name(), test.a, typeid(test.b).name(), test.b);`

Comment: I'm curious. Is this some kind of standard format?

Comment: @whooot - Nope.  Just a stab at something that sorta fits the OP's presumed "requirement".

Answer (score 1):

Use [fprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) if you want your file to be human readable, writing the file using code like

```
void writeArrayToFile(struct A* array, int count)
{
    int i;
    FILE* fp;
    // open file

    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d,%d\n", array[i].a, array[i].b);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: @Jimm It is. And now what?

Comment: ... also it does not preserve the variables types.

Comment: @Jimm Can you update your question to show how you format your data before the `write` call, how your output file is currently structured and how you'd like it to appear please?  It sounds like H2CO3, whooot and I may all have misunderstood what you're asking.  If many users aren't understanding your question, re-wording it would be useful.

Comment: @alk Depends on your interpretation of the question I guess.  I thought the question was just about getting human readable output (as opposed to using `write(fp, &myint, sizeof(myint))`)

Comment: Jimm did not downvote ...

Comment: With this: "*...  How can i preserve the "typness" of a variable. By typeness i mean that if the variable is of type int, the regular file should have human readable digits.*" I feel it's very clear what the OP wanted to know.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  Does my suggestion not give a file with human readable digits?  Or are you inferring a request that the type of each field be written out too?

Comment: I don't think the o/p intended to request that.  He's just ignored an answer that explicitly wrote out the type and accepted an equivalent to my answer.